# How is the PC reset on startup?

Tags: digital-logic

I am reading a book about digital design. There it says in a side note that the PC (program counter) is reset to 0x00000000 upon startup. But I am wondering, how is this really done?

There must be a reset button that reads in 0x00000000 at startup? But how is this really done? I mean when we start the computer how do we send the reset signal only at the start? Is there a device that sends a voltage only at the beginning, and then stops?

Answer (score 4):

Generally an IC microcontroller will have a RESET input that will initialize the program counter (and probably a bunch of other things) when it is driven to the active level (typically active low). That can be controlled by a circuit that produces a pulse when the power is first applied to the circuit or perhaps when a physical reset button is pressed.

A simple circuit might consist of a resistor, a capacitor and maybe a diode. The capacitor takes a while to charge so the RESET input is low for a while. That's a **terrible** reset circuit for various reasons but you can find them in the wild.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgch7L.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When the switch is opened, C1  discharges through D1||R1 + R2 while C2 disharges through R2, and then when power is reapplied cleanly (provider you wait long enough for the voltage on C1 to drop sufficiently) a reset pulse is generated that can be cleaned up with a Schmitt-trigger input to a clean pulse of adequate duration to satisfy the requirements for a valid reset.

Of course if the power is not reapplied cleanly (imagine a blip in the power as it is coming up), you don't wait long enough (a brief flicker due to a compressor load starting), or V1 is out of spec for the MCU the reset may not occur or may only be partial and the program could start executing code anywhere that is not prohibited by memory protection logic (or even executing data interpreted as code in some processors).

Hence, it's not uncommon to  use specialized supervisory circuits that generate guaranteed clean reset pulses of adequate duration under all power-up and brownout conditions. Some MCUs even have such circuits built in, some of them are reliable  some less so.

Comment: Thank you, but can you please explain why a pulse is generated when the power is reapplied?

Comment: Why? The pulse is generated to drive the /RESET input so the microcontroller will start from a known state.

Answer (score 2):

Most chips contain internal reset circuitry or then they require external reset circuitry to keep the chip in reset state until conditions such as supply voltage or clock have stabilized.

Reset is just a signal to return the state of whole chip into such state that when reset is released it starts from a known state.

For a CPU it might just mean that the program counter (PC) is preset to some value or the value how to set PC is read from memory so it is vectored. Not all CPUs start code execution by setting PC to 0, so it is very CPU dependent.

The reset signal typically requires to have certain timing to work properly. For example, it might be required to stay active until voltage and clock have been stabilized before releasing the reset, and if further resets are needed, it is likely that the active reset pulse needs to have a certain length of multiple clock cycles for the reset signal to properly propagate throughout the CPU logic to make sure everything is properly reset into default state. It all depends on how archaic or modern CPU you are working with.

Comment: Is the reset signal in this case also a pulse?

Comment: @user394334 If you define "pulse" as a signal that is active only for a certain interval, then yes, the reset signal is a pulse.

Comment: @user394334, MPUs and MCUs don't normally look for a reset pulse, they react to a reset level. It can be asserted for as long as is wanted, then negated to exit reset and allow normal operation. A pulse is not necessary on reset for the MPU/MCU to recognise and act on it